What's the difference, if any, between "verser en pluie" and "saupoudrer"?
What's the difference, if any, between "verser en pluie" and "saupoudrer"?


They are cookery terms and there is the same difference as "pour" and "sprinkle" in English.

@None thanks, verser en pluie = pour,  saupoudrer = sprinkle , verser = ?

The operation is the same in both cases.
Saupoudrer implies that what is poured is dry, powder-like, (typically salt as the verb etymology is sau, i.e. sel + poudrer), pepper, sugar, spice in powder, etc. Saupoudrer also generally implies that the quantity of product poured is small1 and that is stays on the surface of its destination.
The expression verser en pluie is less common. One difference is it can be done with anything that drops. That can be a liquid, grains, beans, or whatever "discontinuous" ingredient. The product is more likely to be incorporated into its destination, to "sink" in it.
1 Even more when used figuratively as commented by @XouDo.

Du point de vue du cuisinier (et non plus du geste) j'y vois une différence : saupoudrer c'est un but décoratif : le saupoudrage une fois la surface visée atteinte reste en surface, en cuisine saupoudrer est équivalent de recouvrir. Verser en pluie, quand ce n'est pas un liquide (comme le rhum sur un baba), implique ensuite un mélange, par exemple on va verser la farine en pluie dans un mélange + ou - liquide avant de mélanger le tout (on ne peut pas dire saupoudrer dans ce cas), ou bien de la pectine pour gélifier une préparation, etc.

What do you mean by "operation"?  The movement made by the cook  (then I agree) or the purpose of the movement (then I don't agree)?

@None Yes, the way it is done, the action.

The gesture is different, because saupoudrer implies you have taken a pinch of salt, spice or other powder, which you release by rubbing your thumb & index. Verser is by dropping from a spoon or container; verser en pluie implies you spread the powder thin by swinging the container back & forth.

@FrançoisJurain Rubbing your thumb and index is a way to do it but definitely not a requirement.

Indeed; the implication is you handle the powder as if it were salt.

On devrait grouper avec l'autre question et examiner les 3 expressions dans la même question, au lieu de saupoudrer le site avec des questions similaires.

@None According to this definition, maybe "garnish" would be a good translation for "saupoudrer"?

On pourrait aussi comparer le saupoudrage des subventions publiques et une pluie de subventions, ce qui n'est pas tout à fait la même chose ;)

@XouDo Oui, c'est le sens de Saupoudrer also generally implies that the quantity of product poured is small.
